# GStreamer: TLS/SSL support not available; install glib-networking

Tags: macos, websocket, webrtc, gstreamer, glib

I'm trying to make a secure WebRTC connection using [GStreamer 1.22 on macOS](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/download/#macos), based on [this example](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-examples/blob/master/webrtc/multiparty-sendrecv/gst/mp-webrtc-sendrecv.c). When trying to connect to the signaling server via `wss://`, I get the following error:

> HTTP/1.1 6 TLS/SSL support not available; install glib-networking

Should the example work out-of-the-box? Is `glib-networking` somewhere in `GStreamer.framework`, and just isn't being found?

Or, if I have to add it manually: How can I do so without creating system-wide dependencies? Everything needs to be self-contained in one folder, which can be moved and sent to customers. So using a package manager to install `glib-networking` system-wide won't do.

In `GStreamer.framework/Libraries/gio/modules/` there's only `libgioopenssl.so`. I've tried loading that manually using `g_module_open_full`, before the call to `gst_init_check`. Loading succeeds, but I still get the above error.

Any help would be appreciated. I've checked the similar questions, but didn't find a solution.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was [already fixed](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-project/-/issues/114#note_2153872) and the [newest binaries from here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/tpm/cerbero/-/jobs/51126990/artifacts/browse) are working correctly.